# AKS Upgrade failed: CloudProviderProfile is not set

Tags: azure-container-service

Our AKS cluster suddenly stopped responding to `az aks` and `kubectl` commands. We tried to do `az aks upgrade` since that has previously been recommended here. First we upgraded successfully from 1.7.7 to 1.7.7, but that didn't fix the cluster state. Next we tried to upgrade from 1.7.7 to 1.7.12. Unfortunately that failed and now the cluster does not seem operational.

Here is the error response at the end for the upgrade command:

```json
{
  "additionalProperties": {
    "endTime": "2018-03-07T14:15:43.7948662Z",
    "error": {
      "code": "ControlPlaneCloudProviderNotSet",
      "message": "CloudProviderProfile is not set"
    },
    "startTime": "2018-03-07T14:14:31.6196846Z",
    "status": "Failed"
  },
  "agentPoolProfiles": null,
  "dnsPrefix": null,
  "fqdn": null,
  "id": null,
  "kubernetesVersion": null,
  "linuxProfile": null,
  "location": null,
  "name": "03ae4ea8-58ef-0c47-8346-64a665d0edf7",
  "provisioningState": null,
  "servicePrincipalProfile": null,
  "tags": null,
  "type": null
}
```

We found a GitHub issue https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/165 in the history which looks similar to what we are seeing here. Is it the same issue?

```
Correlation id: 7377a386-dfef-4c30-923d-b894001e14ac
Location: west-europe
```

GitHub issue for this StackOverflow post: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/229

Comment: AKS managed by Azure platform, please create a support ticket to Azure(via Azure portal), Azure AKS team will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably try to get the context set again by using:

```
az aks get-credentials -n CLUSTER-NAME -g RESOURCE-GROUP
```

Then try a upgrade without setting the version:

```
az aks upgrade -n CLUSTER-NAME -g RESOURCE-GROUP
```

Hopefully, that should get it back up again.